# get the value of QuickFix::Field::OrdType?

Tags: c++, quickfix

I downloaded `QuickFix.dll` from `quickfixengine.org`

When I declare an object which belongs to namespace `QuickFix::Fields`, I cannot get its corresponding base value (I mean char value for `OrdType`, string value for `OrderID` etc). As there are no properties associated with them.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

The code is:

```
......
QuickField::Fields::OrdType ordType;
message.Get(OrdType);//message is a NewOrderSingle 
                     //type object defined prevviously in the code
                     //Now i wish to get the value contained in "ordType" but it has no
                     //properties to access its data member(s)
```

Comment: Can you give a more explicit explanation of what you're trying to do?  Maybe you can provide a snippet of the code you are trying.

Comment: Please stop tagging this "tcp".  It's not a tcp question.  Really, the only tag that's appropriate is "quickfix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to see:

```
QuickField::Fields::OrdType ordType;
message.get(ordType);
char char_value = ordType.getValue();
```

Advice: check out [the class documentation](http://quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/hierarchy.html).  The field base class is `FIX::FieldBase`, which derives into `FIX::StringField`, `FIX::BoolField`, `FIX::IntField`, etc.  All of these have a `getValue()` function which returns the raw field value converted into the proper data type.

Another way to do this (much less legitimate) is to use `Message::getField(int)` which returns the value of a field as a string.  So you could use `std::string str_value = message.get(40);`, but you'd have a string instead of a char (or int or bool or whatever).

Comment: checked through C# visual studio's object browser, it didn't show any properties or functions, checked VC++ visual studio's object browser, it didn't show any properties or functions, VC++ has not got intelliscence, so i declared an object in C# and checked for functions through intelliscence it showed getValue() and other functions

Comment: Not actually, because i figured it out before i saw your answer(no offence meant) but it definitely deserves an upvote and tick as it is the right answer.